# Is there a word for "sensation that some events are related"?

Tags: terminology

Say you find a news article about "Agent Orange" and the next day your English teacher gives you an old text about "Agent Orange". It's not causation or correlation, those terms are "broad" the term I am seeking is sort of a feeling you get.

Comment: ***A coincidence:*** A sequence of events that although accidental seems to have been planned or arranged.

Comment: Ugh. Because *someone* has to say it, the general label applied to such coincidences (as @Josh says) by modern mystics coming from the New Age tradition is ***synchronicity***. And it's just as much a superstition as omens or oracles ever were.

Comment: As I said, the word I am looking for concerns the person, it's his perception that the events are related. synchronicity! yes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good term for that

> [synchronicity](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=Synchronicity+definition&gws_rd=ssl) *noun*:
>
> **1**. the simultaneous occurrence of events that appear significantly related but have no discernible causal connection. "such *synchronicity* is quite staggering" see Google
>
> [Synchronicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity) is the occurrence of two or more events that appear to be meaningfully related but not causally related. Synchronicity holds that such events are "meaningful coincidences". The concept of synchronicity was first defined by Carl Jung, a Swiss psychiatrist, in the 1920s. During his career, Jung furnished several slightly different definitions of it. See Wikipedia

Comment: I think that in the example the *simultaneity* of events is missing.

Comment: @Josh81 - as in, "**synchrony**" *noun*: 1. simultaneous action, development, or occurrence? Or "**synchronicity**," in the sense of two events occurring in close proximity, time-wise? I think, in the second case, the call is rather subjective.

Comment: 61, please. I think synchronicity is more for simultaneous facts,  anyway it may fit the context. :)

Comment: Certainly, 61. But I've had some seriously paradigm-defying personal experiences of *event*-synchronicity. Just sayin  :-) @Josh61